# How do I log method name and parameters with log4net declaratively using attributes?

Tags: log4net

I currently use `Log.DebugFormat` in every method of my app to log the method name:

```
Public Sub Checkout(order As Order)
    Log.DebugFormat(Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name)
    ...
End Sub
```

Is there a better way to do it using attributes with `log4net`, so my method looks cleaner?

Comment: Not with just log4net, no, but something like [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) could do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the method name by using stacktrace in your formatting:

> stacktrace:
>
> Used to output the stack trace of the logging event The
> stack trace level specifier may be enclosed between braces. For
> example, %stacktrace{level}. If no stack trace level specifier is
> given then 1 is assumed  Output uses the format: type3.MethodCall3 >
> type2.MethodCall2 > type1.MethodCall1  This pattern is not available
> for Compact Framework assemblies.